# Adding a Custom keyboard to a textfield

Tags: calculator, keypad

I need to figure out how to add a custom keypad to a textfield.  What I really need is a decimal point and and add button along with the normal numbers and done button.

Any clues anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html

It seems to be quite flexible and allows localization and customization (don't forget that some people use decimal comma instead of point)

[image]

Comment: It looks good but with no add function it doesn't met my needs.  I do not need the comma button as much as the decimal function.  The application is for a small group that uses the decimal point as a unit of money.